# how can I interpret SVD singular vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra

How can I interpret the left/right singular vectors of SVD when choosing the top $m$ ones?

Can I say that they are the basis for the closest space (of dimension $m$) to the column/row space of the original matrix? If so, "closest" under what metric?